# Adding optional field to database - giving me error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

am getting an error when i try saving my form, one of the field is alternative, so you can add it or not but it should still run.

This is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(EntrtyForm form)
    {

        var addForm = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.SerialUser();

        addForm.ser_num = form.SerialNumber;
        addForm.prod_num = form.ProductNumber;

        addForm.UserName = form.UserName;
        addForm.AltUserName = form.AltUserName;

        cp.SerialUsers.Add(addForm);


        cp.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My save button saves 4 fields as seen above, however

```
            addForm.AltUserName = form.AltUserName;
```

is an optional field.
when i run this code it shows null on the database but gives me an error on cp.SaveChanges();

how can i make this optional so it doesnt matter if users enter a field or not..

html code:

```
 <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AltUserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AltUserName, new { @class = "form" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AltUserName)

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your model - the class of the object that is returned from `M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.SerialUser()`? /also, does the exception give any clue about the field that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you removed the [required] attribute from your field in your ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
public string MyAttribute { get; set; }
```

If your field is not a string, make sure that you add a ? keyword like this:

```
public int? MyAttribute { get; set; }
```

Also check that there is no JQuery Validation on your field in client-side.

Note that if you want to disable validation for all your fields, you can modify your controller to do not test for ModelState by removing the ModelState check:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
// TODO:
}
```